# How to migrate WSS 3.0 FBA users to SharePoint 2010?

Tags: migration, wss-3.0

I have created a test site with SharePoint 2010. I am currently using WSS 3.0 using FBA. So how can I migrate the user & user permissions for each site, list, item, column from FBA user mgmt system to SP 2010

Can someone please list the process?

thx

-saumil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built in tools:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg144572.aspx

http://blog.sharepoint-voodoo.net/?p=68

Also check out AvePoint, they are giving away 100GB of volume for their migration tools, which will do this for you.

http://www.avepoint.com/sharepoint-to-sharepoint-migration-docave/

Comment: Voodoo link is awesome!! thanks ! you are God (Jesus!) :)